# NullPointerException when I am trying get orientation of screen

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, screen, orientation

I have got a problem!

Why when I am trying to get screen orientation, my app gets NullPointerException.

Log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:106)
    at adrian.bjd.masterdetail_myapp.MainActivity.getOrientation(MainActivity.kt:25)
    at adrian.bjd.masterdetail_myapp.MainActivity.onClickItem(MainActivity.kt:43)
    at adrian.bjd.masterdetail_myapp.Fragment.MenuFragment.onItemClick(MenuFragment.kt:46)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:339)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1705)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:4171)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$13.run(AbsListView.java:6734)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

My code:

```
fun getOrientation(): Int
{
    val context = applicationContext
    var orientation = 0

    if(context.resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        orientation = 1
    }
    else if(context.resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        orientation = 2
    }

    return orientation
}
```

I am using a Fragments.
Plese help me !

Comment: where do you call `getOrientation`?

Comment: in MainActivity

Comment: but how ... it seems like you created new instance of `MainActivity` by your own (instead of getting instance create by OS) and then called  `getOrientation` which is totally wrong ...

Comment: show where you call it in mainactivity

Comment: fun onClickItem(position: Int)
    {
        Log.v("MainActivity", "onClickItem(): init")
        val orientation = this.getOrientation()

}                           It is in MainActivity class

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling your function **getOrientation()** in onCreate() move to onResume() and Check. this may help

Comment: If you read the stack trace, you can clearly see that that's not where it's being called. This suggestion would not solve that NPE anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use your `context` from your `Fragment` I recommend to you to create this

```
private val mContext by lazy {
    this@YourFragment.context
}
```

And then in your method `getOrientation()` just use `mContext` instead.

If you don't want to use the `lazy` in your `onCreateView()` add this

```
activity = activity as Context
```

And then you can use your `activity` as `context`

Answer (score -1):

You only use getApplicationContext() when you know you need a Context for something that may live longer than any other likely Context you have at your disposal. Scenarios include:

Use getApplicationContext() if you need something tied to a Context that itself will have global scope. I use getApplicationContext(), for example, in WakefulIntentService, for the static WakeLock to be used for the service. Since that WakeLock is static, and I need a Context to get at PowerManager to create it, it is safest to use getApplicationContext().

Use getApplicationContext() when you bind to a Service from an Activity, if you wish to pass the ServiceConnection (i.e., the handle to the binding) between Activity instances via onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(). Android internally tracks bindings via these ServiceConnections and holds references to the Contexts that create the bindings. If you bind from the Activity, then the new Activity instance will have a reference to the ServiceConnection which has an implicit reference to the old Activity, and the old Activity cannot be garbage collected.

and in  case you want to get the current orientation then you can use :

Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation

Instead of calling this with application context , use below

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if( (newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE))
    {                    mainBinding.layoutDrawerView.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    }
}
```